# Gitlab - Repositorios en 2 cuentas distintas como hacer push?

Tags: git, github, git-push, gitlab, git-commit

tengo 2 cuentas de **gitlab** una personal y otra para el trabajo, desarrollo proyectos desde el mismo pc y tengo el problema que con el del curro tengo las KEYS en el pc y cuando hago un push me dice la passphrase y listos.

Pero ahora he creado un repositorio nuevo en gitlab com mi cuenta personal y al intentar hacer un push me dice que el repo no existe (creo porque me pilla las claves de la otra cuenta), como puedo hacer para solucionar esto?

```
PS C:\Apache24\htdocs\testProject> git remote add origin https://gitlab.com/fake-user/test-symfony.git 
fatal: remote origin already exists.

PS C:\Apache24\htdocs\testProject> git branch -M main
PS C:\Apache24\htdocs\testProject> git push -uf origin main

remote: The project you were looking for could not be found or you don't have permission to view it.
fatal: repository 'https://gitlab.com/fake-user/test-symfony.git/' not found
```

Thxs

Comment: cambia los settings para este repo en local: `git config user.email <tu email>`, `git config user.name <tu nombre>`, `git config user.password <tu contraseña>`. Nótese que no uso `--global`, pues afectaría a todos los repos

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' en `git help config` no vi que se pueda configurar `user.password` (git 2.30.2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto se resuelve a nivel de ssh.

En ssh, se pueden definir varios *hosts* indicando cual llave usar para cada uno. Los nombres que uses entonces puedes ser usados en URLs de ssh (como los que dan github o gitlab) para que git (en realidad ssh) sepa cual host/llave hay que usar en cada caso.

Esto lo estoy armando sin probarlo, así que podría haber alguno que otro problema al probarlo... pero el concepto debe funcionar:

~/.ssh/config

```
Host gh-personal github.com
    HostName github.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/rsa_personal # llave privada usuario personal en gh
    User git

Host gh-trabajo github.com
    HostName github.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/rsa_trabajo  # llave privada usuario trabajo en gh
    User git
```

Luego de esto, en los URLs de los repos que vayas a utilizar, en los personales usas el hostname `gh-personal` y en los de trabajo `gh-trabajo`:

```
git clone gh-personal:foo/bar.git
git clone gh-trabajo:blah/blah.git
```

Referencia:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419566/best-way-to-use-multiple-ssh-private-keys-on-one-client